# Copy past from ms word to WordPress with content style and color scheme

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, copy-paste

When I copy content from an MS Word file to the WordPress editor, colour schemes are not being pasted.
is there any way to achieve it?

**Content on word as shown**

[image: red, blue, black text in Word]

**Content on WordPress editor**

[image: black text in a different font]

That's how it paste on WordPress classical editor
How can I achieve it

Comment: I know nothing about Word Press. Try, in Word, saving as a web page and then importing that into Word Press.

Comment: I have saved it as web page then copy the CSS and Html tags to WordPress page working very well.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save as a web page and then copy from that into WordPress.